# What is a good process I/O rate?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, io, devops, azure-application-insights

I have conducted a performance testing on e-commerce website and trying to find some bottlenecks. From Azure application insight>performance i checked the process I/O rate.
[image]

As you can see from the picture the process I/O rate was 33.57 during the performance test duration. But i am not sure if that's a good or not. Can please advise me on what is a good I?o rate for e-commerce application? Thanks

Comment: Have you gone through this Url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing

Answer (score 1):

Over millions of recorded servers in the Live Optics program the Read Ratio is 69% and the average IO Transfer size is 34.4K. Just for simplicity sake, let's round to 32K. Most environments will not have a single IO transfer size.